# Difference between Explicit conversions and safe cast in c#

Tags: c#, casting, explicit

First one is working, while second shows an error, what is the difference? 
I read documentation, and didnt find anything about it, it not so crucial but want to know some features

```
public static string GetConcat2<T>(T q)
    {
        if(q.GetType() == typeof(A))
        {
            var z = q as A;
        }
        if (q.GetType() == typeof(A))
        {
            var z = (A)q;
        }
        return "!!!!";
    }
public interface CustomInteface
{
    string InterfaceProperty1 { get; set; }
    string InterfaceProperty2 { get; set; }
    string Concat();
}
public class A : CustomInteface
{
    public string InterfaceProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string InterfaceProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string Concat() {
        return InterfaceProperty1 + InterfaceProperty2;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error, where does it throw the error? Try to provide all of the information and code necessary to reproduce the issue, Include a [MCVE].

Comment: @TheLethalCoder
var z = (A)q; 

here's an error, it couldnt cast to type A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `var z = (A)q;` is throwing an error this means that the object `q` is not of type `A`. The way you are trying to cast is a bit awkward as well you should use one of the following patterns:

- `as` followed by `null` check:

  ```
  var z = q as A;
  if (z == null) { /*the cast failed*/ }
  ```
- `is` followed by explicit cast

  ```
  if (q is A)
  {
      var z = (A)q;
  }
  ```

Note the first pattern will return `null` if the cast fails and the second will throw an exception. This is why you only see the exception in the second case as the first is "silently" failing.

Comment: as u can see, i'm checking generic type, so it must be correct type
     if (q.GetType() == typeof(A))

Comment: @GodlikeRabbit Yes but don't do it that way, try doing it in the proper ways. Also debug your application and see what `q` actually is.